# Objects arranged as a graph

Tags: algorithm, matlab, graph-theory

I want to arrange many objects of a certain class as a graph in Matlab. The goal is, that when I create a new object it automatically is added to the graph. However, as far as I can see graphs only accept numbers when I add a new node. How is typically dealt with it? Should I have a `GroupClass` that holds all the objects and a graph with the relations? What I would like to have is something like

```
G = graph()
O1 = createObject(G)
O2 = createObject(G)
```

and in createObject something like

```
...
G.addnode(O1)
G.addedge(O1,O2)
...
```

Afterwards I want to be able to plot the relations, print out groups or all nodes, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding nodes as a ["node properties"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.addnode.html#buofhlk-1-nodeIDs) `table`. Here's a very simple example:

```
G = graph();
for idx = 1:10
    % make a single-row table containing the name and data
    % associated with this node
    nodeProps = table({['Idx ', num2str(idx)]}, ...
        MException('msg:id', sprintf('Message %d', idx)), ...
        'VariableNames', {'Name', 'Data'});
    G = addnode(G, nodeProps);
end
for idx = 2:10
    % add edges based on the node names
    G = addedge(G, 'Idx 1', sprintf('Idx %d', idx));
end
plot(G)
```